# how i could copy a document to an inside folder in document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

what i want is i want to copy a document (or item) exist inside my document library into a folder exist also inside the same document library.
any help please:

i tried that but no way: i want make copy

```
  public void MoveItemInsideFolder(SPListItem item, string path)
    {
        //Path like 'Folder1/Folder2/'
        switch (item.FileSystemObjectType)
        {
            case SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder:
                var newFolder = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", 
    item.ParentList.RootFolder.Url, path, item.Folder.Name);
                item.Folder.MoveTo(newFolder);
                break;
            case SPFileSystemObjectType.File:
                var file = item.Web.GetFile(item.Url);
                var newFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}_.000", 
  item.ParentList.RootFolder.Url, path, item.ID);
                file.MoveTo(newFilePath);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing this with some of my own code I believe there are two issues here.  Firstly your not doing a file (or folder) update after the move e.g. file.Update().  Secondly I think the path has to be Server Relative, the one your using is web relative.

So taking your code I've done a version for document libraries:

```
public void MoveItemInsideFolder(SPListItem item, string path)
{
    //Path like 'Folder1/Folder2/'
    switch (item.FileSystemObjectType)
    {
        case SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder:
            SPFolder folder = item.Folder;
            var newFolder = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", item.ParentList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, path, folder.Name);
            folder.MoveTo(newFolder);
            folder.Update()
            break;
        case SPFileSystemObjectType.File:
            SPFile file = item.File;
            var newFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", item.ParentList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, path, item.Name);
            file.MoveTo(newFilePath);
            file.Update();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as :

```
 case SPFileSystemObjectType.File:
                    var file = item.Web.GetFile(item.Url);
                    var newFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}_.000",
                    item.ParentList.RootFolder.Url, path, item.ID);
                    file.MoveTo(newFilePath);
```

I am not able to understand your folder moving login.
Can you please explain that.

Also you can use                     `file.CopyTo(newFilePath);` to copy the files.